# Swift: Webview prompt dialog box to reload the current page when network is not available

Tags: ios, swift, http, wkwebview

I am new to iOS App development. I have a sample App which is written in Swift.
I am using a WKWebView in my web application.

However, when the mobile network/Wifi is  not available. It is showing blank screen.

I would like to prompt a dialog box to refresh the current page to the user when
1. If network is not present
2. My server is not available to be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebView` delegate method to find network error.

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView )webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError )error
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)error.code];
    if ([str isEqualToString: @"-1009"])//network unavailable error code
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Internet or Wifi is not available. Please check your network connection & try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        str = @"";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[super appUrl]);

}
```

Then retry in AlertView delegate method

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex==0){
        if ([super appUrl]) {
            NSURLRequest* appReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:yourURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
            [self.webView loadRequest:appReq];
        }    }
}
```

P.S. use similar to work with swift.